JXLS- How to add some information after writing a list in excel file?
It can be written an item list to the excel file. I want to add some details after the list. But I do not know the size of list. List is written with this comment:
jx:each(items="models" var="m" lastCell="AA13").
Title1              Title2                 Title3
${m.title1}         ${m.title2}            ${m.title3}
                Total:                 Total Number
                Extra information.

I tried to add jx:each(items="models" var="m" lastCell="AA13") this comment to "Total" cell.

Title1 Title2 Title3 ${m.title1} ${m.title2} ${m.title3} --> this  represents excel cells for the list
